# Differences between blue background and black background PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering why the background of the PowerShell is different when I open it from Run (or Start) and from the shortcut on desktop PowerShell.exe. In the first case the background is blue, in the latter case it's black.

Are there other differences between the two windows of the PowerShell?

---

EDIT
[image]
[image]

---

EDIT 2: in the figure below you can see the powershell processes. Moreover, if I open powershell.exe directly from C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0, the background is blue instead of black (remember that its link on desktop opens a black background powershell).

Regarding the below figure, both processes powershell.exe and Windows PowerShell are located in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0.

P.S.: the situation described here is the same on Windows 10 and 7.

[image]

---

EDIT 3
[image]
[image]

If I go in the folder C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 and I right click on powershell.exe, there isn't the tab Colours, but its link on Desktop has the tab Colours.

Comment: It's the same, it's just the color. You should check out the new terminal (by microsoft), it's a lot nicer [windows terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/)

Comment: I suspect the shortcut doesn't point to powershell.exe, but is a shortcut to the command prompt cmd.exe

Comment: Hello @Theo see the edit please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there other differences between the two windows of the PowerShell?

Probably yes but it's likely to be on the same level. (e.g. from your screenshot the blue console is wider so probably has a higher Width layout setting).
afaics it looks they're both the same powershell.exe with different host settings. But only you can confirm.

**How to check if they're the same "PowerShell"**

- Open `Task Manager` > `Details` tab.
  You should see 2 processes with name `powershell.exe`.
- Right click > `Properties` and look at the Location
  I suspect they're both `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

---

**Why is one black and the other blue?**

- Right click on desktop shortcut > `Properties` > `Colours`
  These settings are applied when you open PowerShell using this shortcut.
- You can do the same for the `Windows PowerShell` shortcut in the start menu.
  (You may have to right click > Open file location to get to the actual shortcut)
- For Run > `powershell.exe`, it's using the settings in the registry as described [here](https://github.com/neilpa/cmd-colors-solarized/issues/18).

---

**Edit:** So running the `powershell.exe` directly uses the settings stored in the registry at path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe`. Copying and pasting a shortcut does not copy these settings because they are not stored in the exe. I believe but am I not certain that shortcuts will use the settings in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\` by default. You need to edit the properties to change the settings for the shortcut. You could edit them in the registry but this seems like a bad idea as it's not just used by PowerShell.

---

**Related stuff**

- You can change the defaults in the `Properties` above.
- `Options`, `Font` and `Layout` settings may also differ.
- You can see the values for the current console (including run > `powershell.exe`) by clicking on the PowerShell logo in the top left and going to `Properties`
- related links: [**`$Host`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#host), [**`Get-Host`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-host?view=powershell-5.1) and (if using `PSReadLine` module) [**`Get-PSReadLineOption`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#host), [**`Set-PSReadLineOption`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-host?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: the only think I didn't get is why if I open powershell.exe in the folder, the background is blue, instead if I open its shortcut, the background is black. The shortcut should keep the same settings of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didnt know but you send me on the right path.
Black is the x64 version and blue is the x86 version.
If it was up to me microsoft would the delete the x86 version and set the black one to the font and colour setup of the blue one.

Black target: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Blue target: %SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

[HowToFix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3WOF.png)

Copy everything from blue powershell to black one and fixed!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35380596)