# PowerShell - Start another instance of PowerShell.exe without elevation and using -NoProfile

Tags: windows, powershell, processstartinfo, start-process, process-elevation

I'm trying to run a new instance of powershell.exe (from PowerShell/ISE/pwsh/VSCode) with lowered elevation using its `-NoProfile` switch but haven't figured out a way to pass the `-NoProfile` switch in a way that results in a newly non-elevated PowerShell console that uses the custom colors/layout that it normally would when double-clicking powershell.exe from an Explorer window.

There seem to be two fairly common approaches to lowering elevation from an elevated host/console:

1. Using `runas.exe /trustlevel:0x20000 powershell.exe`

   - The console window doesn't use the custom layout/colors it typically displays with and will usually present as a black console window.

     - There is a SO question on the differences between the blue and black consoles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862733/differences-between-blue-background-and-black-background-powershell).
     - Lee Holmes also has a short [blog](https://www.leeholmes.com/powershells-noble-blue/) about this.
2. Taking advantage of explorer.exe's (default) lower trust level and doing something like this:
   `Start-Process $env:SystemRoot\explorer.exe $PSHome\powershell.exe`

   - If the user has disabled UAC, then explorer.exe will be running with elevation anyways, so this method isn't as reliable as using `runas.exe /trustlevel:0x20000 powershell.exe`

I've tried:

- `runas.exe /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell.exe -NoProfile"`

  - Works, but opens a black console window.
- `runas.exe /trustlevel:0x20000 "explorer.exe powershell.exe -NoProfile"`

  - opens an Explorer window.
- Various combinations and overloads using `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::new()` and `[System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]::new()` without success.
- Using various forms of `start /b "" xyz` without success.

Is there another approach that would work better?  Editing the registry to set the default console layout/colors isn't impossible, but it's not the most ideal or solid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is the *startup* window title of a console (`conhost.exe`) window that determines what settings to apply, taken from the registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\<transformed-exe-path>]`, where `<transformed-exe-path>` is the full path of the executable with `\` characters replaced with `_`, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73781371/45375).
- With `runas.exe /trustlevel:0x20000` you'll get a *custom* windows title, which invariably *appends* the following to the startup command line: `(running as <computer>\<user> with restricted privileges)` - and since such a title is unlikely to have a specific subkey in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]`, the *default* console settings apply.

The simplest way to work around this is to call via `cmd /c start` in order to start a *new* window - either relying on the new window's target executable's path to select the right settings or by specifying an explicit startup title:

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 'cmd /c start powershell.exe -noprofile'
```

Note:

- This will create *two* console windows: a *transient* one for `cmd /c`, and the target one created by `start` - hopefully, the transient one will be too short-lived to have a visual impact.
- In Windows 11, up to at least version 22H2, there is currently [a *bug*](https://superuser.com/q/1749696/139307) that prevents use of `/trustlevel` without also providing a `/machine` argument with the current machine *architecture*:

  ```
  runas "/machine:$($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.ToLower())" /trustlevel:0x20000 'cmd /c start powershell.exe -noprofile'
  ```
- If you need to specify an explicit window title for the `start`-launched process, things get tricky, because that title must be `"..."` enclosed, which - due to a long-standing PowerShell bug with respect to passing arguments with embedded `"` chars. to external programs (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)) - must *manually* be escaped as `\"`; e.g., to set custom title `Custom Title`:

  ```
  # A solution that works in v7.3+ too
  & {
    $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'
    # Note: /machine argument omitted for brevity.
    runas /trustlevel:0x20000 'cmd /c start \"Custom Title\" powershell.exe -noprofile'
  }
  ```

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you!
LOL - "There's a bug in Windows 11."

Comment: @Paulπ :) my pleasure. Re the bug: I've only ever tried the `"/machine:$($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.ToLower())"`  workaround on an ARM64 machine - I hope it works on x64 / x86 machines too.